# Intel Xeon Gold 6140 and Windows 10

Tags: windows, intel, xeon

Can I use following setup with Windows 10 or do I need Windows Server?

CPU - 1x Intel® Xeon® Gold 6140 Processor

MB - ASUS WS-C621E-SAGE

Comment: Windows Server 2016 is windows 10 without the spam and with a role centralization system added.

Answer (score 1):

Windows 10 (Pro, x64) supports 2 sockets with 256 logical cores and up to 512GB RAM, so no problem here.

To be more precise, Windows 10 supports a maximum memory configurations that was formerly available only in the realm of servers:

- Windows 10 Home supports up to 128GB of RAM (x64).
- Windows 10 Pro and Enterprise support up to 512GB (x64)
- Windows 10 x86 (32 bit) supports a maximum of 4GB RAM

In general, all Windows 10 editions support a maximum of two physical CPUs, but the number of logical processors or cores varies based on the processor architecture. For example, a maximum of 32 cores is supported in 32-bit versions of Windows 8/10, whereas up to 256 cores are supported in the 64-bit versions.

The [Intel® Xeon® Gold 6140](https://ark.intel.com/products/120485/Intel-Xeon-Gold-6140-Processor-24_75M-Cache-2_30-GHz) has 18 cores (with 36 Hyper-threading 'cores'), I don't see any CPU-Related problems here.

Comment: any the 6140 is well within the 205W per socket TDP limit too at 140W

Answer (score 0):

Sure you can. The only difference is that it was created for server purposes, to been able to run specific apps etc. But you can install regular W10 on this hardware.